# Python modifying List inside a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

How to modify a dict of lists?
for example:
if I have a dict:

```py
my_dict = {'numbers':[1,2,3],
'numbers2':[4,5,6]
'numbers3':[7,8,9]}
```

How do I, for example,
do I multiply all numbers by 3?
output:

```
my_dict = {'numbers':[3,6,9],
'numbers2':[12,15,18]
'numbers3':[21,24,27]}
```

Comment: Do you know how to modify all values of a plain list? In other words, is your problem modifying *something* in a dict *or* modifying everything in a list?

Answer (score 0):

You just do it entry by entry.

```
for k in my_dict:
    my_dict[k] = [i*3 for i in my_dict[k]]
```

Note that I am creating a new list, rather than modifying the existing one in place.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's method is the easiest to understand if you're using raw Python lists. If you're using Numpy arrays, however, you could use a dict comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

my_dict = { "a": np.array([1, 2, 3]), "b": np.array([4, 5, 6]), "c": np.array([7, 8, 9]) }

my_dict = { k: v * 3 for k, v in my_dict.items() }
```